# Magento Warning Error in loading from Autoload.php on line 93

Tags: magento

Please check I am migrating a Magento website to my local XAMPP and I am getting below Warning.

I did not find the file Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php

```
Warning: include(Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(Mage\Co...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 93, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Front\Action.php(35): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\lib\Varien\Autoload.php(93): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#5 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Cms\controllers\IndexController.php(36): spl_autoload_call('Mage_Core_Contr...')
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(337): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(308): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_includeControllerClass('C:\xampp\htdocs...', 'Mage_Cms_IndexC...')
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(196): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->_validateControllerClassName('Mage_Cms', 'index')
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/warning-includefile-php-failed-in-autoload-php-on-line-93

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: might be there are some missing. try to upload `app/code/core` folder from a fresh magento.

Answer (score 0):

*I did not find the file Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php*

`app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php` - a file that should not be missing in any Magento install I've ever worked with.

If it exists on the working website and not on your XAMPP website, then your transfer method failed. This is quite common with (s)ftp transfers and Magento Connect install/upgrade(s), you have to run them multiple times until everything actually is present.

If you are going to do a file by file transfer, you are better off using `rsync` as it will do a synchronization transfer that allows for recovery from partial transfers by only copying over what is missing on subsequent runs.

It is often better to create a compressed tar archive of the live server document root, transfer that and dearchive it on your server you are transferring to. This guarantees:

1. you get all the files on the running installation
2. are able to restore all the files from the running installation to the new installation
3. get a warning if the archive is corrupted so you aren't wasting time with trying to make a partial Magento install to run

Comment: Thanks ! Agian i am getting this Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 13: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in C:\xampp\htdocs\agandearth.com.au\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout\Update.php on line 450